# Suppose that the sum of $11$ different natural numbers is $70$. How can I show that their product is divisible by $720$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm having difficulties to solve this problem for a 6th grade kid:

> The sum of $11$ different natural numbers is $70$. Show that their product is divisible by $720$.

Comment: Naturals numbers?

Comment: @ovetz13 yes. I edited the question. I managed to reach something like this: 11*x + Q = 70. Where x is natural, not 0

Comment: @FlorinM. Just so you know, you accepted the wrong answer.

Comment: I undo the accepted answer

Comment: It's expected that you will show what you have tried and where you are stuck

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The lowest eleven numbers we can pick are those from $1$ to $11$, and they sum to $66$, so we only have to add $4$ to one (or more) of them to make $70$. By keeping in mind that the numbers must be distinct, the only five possibilities are:
$$\begin{align}
&(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15)\tag{11 + 4}\\
&(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 14)\tag{10 + 4}\\
&(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13)\tag{9 + 4}\\
&(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12)\tag{8 + 4}\\
&(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 13)\tag{10 + 2, 11 + 2}\\
\end{align}$$

(Why we cannot add $1$ and $3$ is left to the reader.)

Now, $720 = 6! = 2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6,$ and as it can be seen those factors are always present.

---

Note: It's not really needed to enumerate all the possibilities because we just have to prove that the product $6!$ is always present, and that follows from the fact that we cannot add $4$, $3$, $2$, $1$ to any of the numbers $1-6$ because otherwise we would have duplicates. Still, I believe that a 6th grader might understand the problem better if you let them derive all the possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

$$1+2+3+..+11=66$$
So we have to put 4 to one of the numbers so the sum is 70. There are few options. $11+4$, $10+4$, $9+4$ or $8+4$.
So we have the numbers:
$$1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*10*14$$
$$1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9*14*11$$
$$1*2*3*4*5*6*7*8*13*10*11$$
$$1*2*3*4*5*6*7*12*9*10*11$$

Comment: Why not also 7 + 4? The sum will also be 70. The 11th number which we want to be modified ( + 4 ) can be chosen aleatory ?

Comment: The numbers have to be different $7+4=11$ which we already have.

Comment: This is incorrect because you can split the $4$ and add it to different numbers. There are five possibilities, not four.

Comment: @rubik You are right, I do think there are 5 cases

Comment: To elaborate: this answer is not incorrect *per se*, but if fails to conclude the reasoning.